# I cannot figure out why my file is not writing out

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

ifstream initialCost;
ofstream output;
output.open("output.txt");
initialCost.open("InitialCost.txt");
float csh1, af1, tr1, csh2, af2, tr2,tcsh1, tcsh2;

initialCost >> csh1 >> af1 >> tr1 >> csh2 >> af2 >> tr2;

tcsh1 =csh1+ (5*(csh1*tr1))+(5*af1);
tcsh2 =csh2+ (5*(csh2*tr2))+(5*af2);

cout<< "Initial House cost"<< '\t'
    << "Annual Fuel Cost" << '\t'
    << "Tax Rate" << '\t'
    << "Total Cost"<< '\n'
    << csh1 << '\t' << af1<< '\t' << tr1 << '\t' << tcsh1 << '\n'
    << csh2 << '\t' << af2<< '\t' << tr2 << '\t' << tcsh2 << '\n';



return 0;
}
```

My outputs are weird and I can't figure out why my second set of outputs are not working like the first. Also I need my outputs to write into the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
cout<< "Initial House cost"<< '\t'
```

to

```
output<< "Initial House cost"<< '\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't you meant to have commas in this line:

```
initialCost >> csh1 >> af1 >> tr1 >> csh2, af2, tr2;
```

And writing to a file is done just like writing to `std::cout`, both are output streams and works the same.

Comment: I still cannot get the values to write into my output.txt

Comment: @AlexJonMartinWalter Instead of outputting to `cout`, do the same with `output`. E.g. `output << "Hello world\n";` should put the string `Hello world` and a newline into the file.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: @adripanico It happens automatically when the stream object goes out of scope. And the close of course flushes the buffers first.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg after a little research I must say you are right :) But... if you don't close the file you could not check the goodbit :D